# Android Progressbar next to Autocompletetextview not able to hide appropriately

Tags: android, progress-bar, autocompletetextview, android-filterable

I have a `AutoCompleteTextView` and `ProgressBar` right of it and visibility of `ProgressBar` is invisible at beginning.

I am setting adapter to AutocompleteTextView in onCreate of my activity with custom class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter and xml file autocomplete which contains the TextView,

```
actvFrom.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
            R.layout.autocomplete));
```

In `PlacesAutocompleteAdapter` class i am implementing `Filterable` interface.

```
private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
        implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {

        android.widget.Filter filter = new android.widget.Filter() {

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }

            }



            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(
                    final CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    resultList = autocomplete_fill_data(constraint
                            .toString());


                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }

                return filterResults;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
}
```

In autocomplete_fill_data function i am doing call to the server and adding it to ArrayList myCollection and returning it.

```
public ArrayList<String> autocomplete_fill_data(String value) {

    myCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

  // call to server
    ...

     myCollection.add(result);
   return myCollection;

 }
```

AutoComplete is working fine but the problem is i am not able to show the `ProgressBar` whenever there is call to server.

I tried all this,

- Using addTextChangedListener

  autocomplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  ```
          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                  int count) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if (s.length() >= 1) {
                  System.out.println("Count ="+count);
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


              } else {
                   progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              }

          }
  ```

But Problem with this is even though you stopped typing text the progressBar will be still rotating. I wanted to hide the ProgressBar as soon as the user stops writing the text.

- In performFiltering i tried to hide the progressBar but the autocomplete box is getting stuck as you type.

Is there any other way so i can try to hide the progressBar as the user stops typing the text.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use 
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)

```
 autocomplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
 {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that but what happens is as soon as you type the text it will become invisible. So that progressBar wont be visible at all.